# Android app name in Arabic for Android 2.2

Tags: android, eclipse, arabic

The app name in Arabic is showing broken i.e characters are appearing separately. I am using android 2.2. How can i solved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on the installed ROM, google officially started supporting Arabic Ice Cream, but some manufacture supported arabic since 2.1 on their devices like Samsung, and most of Arab Users dont have problems about arabic language on their devices right now.

Answer (score 0):

android officially start Arabic support with their honeycomb series i.e  android 3.0 onward
so if u wanna use arabic u must use proper formatted arabic u need to use formatting tools

as far your question is concerned app_name will be fine in android 3 onward but for 2.2 you either give image icon or leave it as it is (i will prefer second)